# Printing out the string with most occurences of a specific char, in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I need to print out the string from a string array, which has the most occurences of a specific char.

Examples:

`{"I","have","feelings"} , 'e'` prints "feelings".

`{"doodlidoo","foo","moon"} , 'o'` prints"doodlidoo".

So far I have come up with this, which finds the length of each string. I just need to figure out how I can print the individual string.

```
 public static String MostLettersInWord(String[] list, char c)
 {
    for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
     {
      int count = list[x].Split(c).Length - 1;
     }
     return list[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways of doing so, but going by your way and keeping it simple and basic, just add a comparison functionality here

```
string answer;
int prevCount = 0, count = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
{
     int count = list[x].Split(c).Length - 1;
     if(count>prevCount)
     {
         answer = list[x];
         prevCount = count;
     }


}
return answer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var word = words.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count(z => z == c)).First();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jvlHvN).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with LINQ:

```
string result = list.OrderByDescending(str => str.Max(m => m == c)).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be looking for all words with the same maximum number of particular char the following query will select them:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "I", "have", "feelings", "meet" };

char ch = 'e';
var results =
    words
    .Where(w => w.Contains(ch))
    .Select(w => new
    {
        Word = w,
        CharCount = w.Count(c => c.Equals(ch))
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CharCount)
    .GroupBy(x => x.CharCount)
    .First()
    .Select(x => x.Word)
    .ToList();
```